# What's the meaning of clearing up

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, idiom-meaning

Trying to understand the meaning of "clearing up".

One of the meanings I see at [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/clear-up) is

> When you clear up or clear a place up, you make things neat and put
>   them away.

Here's some excerpt to give some context.

```
MOUSE - RUNNN!

UNICORN - Hop onto my back!

UNICORN - I see a clearing up ahead!

MOUSE - That's not a clearing! It's the edge of a cliff!
```

Comment: ..it is "a clearing/ up ahead"

Comment: Translate that to "I see a clearing, and that clearing is up ahead of us". I'm going to vote to close as a misinterpretation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a misinterpretation of the sentence.

Comment: what does he mean by clearing? the way is open?

Comment: "Clearing" in this case is an open un-wooded area in a forest.

Comment: @Cascabel that's the one, bravo

Comment: Can someone explain what is the misinterpretation in the question, I'm confused.

Comment: @AppDeveloper The misinterpretation is that _clearing_ and _up_ belong together in the sentence; they don’t. Consider if he’d said, “I see a car further ahead” – if someone sees that and then asks what a ‘car further’ is, they’ve misinterpreted the sentence, because a ‘car further’ isn’t a unit in the sentence at all.

Comment: Your misinterpretation is in the title of your question —  “clearing up”. In the sentence “I see a clearing up ahead!” there are 3 parts: "I see", "a clearing", "up ahead."

Comment: so there should be a comma, "I see a clearing, up ahead", if that's right I can edit the question to fix it.

Comment: No comma — it doesn't mean “let's go” or “let's run”, it means simply that **it is** there. English is sometimes strange for foreigners as it often use prepositions in places where other languages not — e.g “sit down” instead of  using simply “sit”,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your context it is a **clear place in a wood (a forest)** — probably there were trees sometimes ago, but people chopped they down.

[image]

Comment: awesome, great visual and the explanation.

Comment: wish I could upvote, I don't have enough reputations.